# Handler deprecated

Tags: java, android, android-studio, deprecated

I'm starting now in mobile development but I'm not able to advance my studies due to a depreciation error I found. I found the solution but I can't implement it, could someone help me?

**Solution found**

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Your Code
    }
}, 3000);
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.studywithmeoficial;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView imagePlayPause;
    private TextView textCurrentTime, textTotalDuration;
    private SeekBar playerSeekBar;

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_mapa, R.id.navigation_casa, R.id.navigation_musica)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);

        //seria meio que, leia aquilo que possui o ID = imagePlayPause
        imagePlayPause = findViewById(R.id.imagePlayPause);
        textCurrentTime = findViewById(R.id.textCurrentTime);
        textTotalDuration = findViewById(R.id.textTotalDuration);
        playerSeekBar = findViewById(R.id.playerSeekBar);


        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        playerSeekBar.setMax(100);


        imagePlayPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                {
                    handler.removeCallbacks(updater);
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    //trocar a imgem do botão
                    imagePlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                }else{
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    imagePlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                    updateSeekBar();
                }
            }
        });

        prepareMediaPlayer();


        playerSeekBar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) view;
                int playPosition = (mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 100) * seekBar.getProgress();
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(playPosition);
                textCurrentTime.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
                return false;
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i) {
                playerSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(i);
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                playerSeekBar.setProgress(0);
                imagePlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                textCurrentTime.setText(R.string.zero);
                textTotalDuration.setText(R.string.zero);
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                prepareMediaPlayer();
            }
        });
        
    }

    private void prepareMediaPlayer()
    {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=orJSJGHjBLI"); //URL do arquivo de musica
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            textTotalDuration.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getDuration()));
        } catch (Exception exception){
            Toast.makeText(this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateSeekBar();
            long currentDuration =  mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            textCurrentTime.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));
        }
    };

    private void updateSeekBar()
    {
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            playerSeekBar.setProgress((int) (((float) mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / mediaPlayer.getDuration()) * 100));
            handler.postDelayed(updater, 1000);
        }
    }


    private String milliSecondsToTimer(long milliSeconds)
    {
        String timerString = "";
        String secondsString;

        int hours = (int)(milliSeconds / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        int minutes = (int)(milliSeconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60);
        int seconds = (int)((milliSeconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) % (1000 * 60) / 1000);

        if(hours > 0)
        {
            timerString = hours + ":";
        }

        if(seconds < 10)
        {
            secondsString = "0" + seconds;
        } else{
            secondsString = "" + seconds;
        }

        timerString  = timerString + minutes + ":" + secondsString;

        return timerString;
        
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.studywithmeoficial">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.StudyWithMeOficial"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="m">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**screen_music.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.music.MusicFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_notifications"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="396dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"   />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagePlayPause"
        android:layout_width="43dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_play"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nomeMusica"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:text="@string/nomeMusica"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imagePlayPause"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/linhaSeparacao2"
        android:layout_width="762dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="@string/separacao"
        android:textColor="#212121"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nomeMusica"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/linhaDeSeparacao"
        android:layout_width="420dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="127dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="584dp"
        android:text="@string/separacao"
        android:textColor="#212121"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.555"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="94dp"
        android:layout_height="92dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="200dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/nomeMusica"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPiano"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/piano_cello"
            tools:ignore="contentDescription"

            />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.399"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.149">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textCurrentTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/zero"
            android:textColor="#212121"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/playerSeekBar"
            android:layout_width="116dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTotalDuration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/zero"
            android:textColor="#212121"
            android:textSize="16sp" />


    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**error in MainActivity**

warning: [deprecation] Handler() in Handler has been deprecated

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
                   ^
```

Comment: `private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());`.

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you very much